# How to permanently remove an element from a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is the problem.

I have code like this where I get all li elements into a jQuery collection and then I remove last item from DOM. But I don't know how to also remove an element from a jQuery collection?

Now it's something like this:

```
 console.log(myList);
['li.item', 'li.item', 'li.item']
```

I need to pop last item and get something like this:

```
console.log(myList);
['li.item', 'li.item']
```

```js
var myList = $('.item');

console.log(myList);

myList.last().remove();

console.log(myList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: You can just create a new jQuery object with that selector to get a current list of elements.

Comment: It's easy to use splice or pop. But the question how to remove item with collection getting updated - is an interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove an element in the jQuery object, you can use `.splice()`.

To remove the last element :

```
myList.splice(-1);
```

To remove the first element :

```
myList.splice(0, 1);
```

**It is important to know that the returned value is an HTMLElement.** If you wanna do something with it, you need to convert it into a jQuery element again.

---

Unfortunatly, jQuery doesnt have `pop` or `shift` by default. But you can easily create those methods with that :

```
$.fn.pop = function(){
    return $(this.splice(-1));
}

$.fn.shift = function(){
    return $(this.splice(0,1));
}
```

Then call:

```
myList.pop();
myList.shift();
```

---

If you want to remove in the DOM and in the object, you can chain the remove function :

```
myList.pop().remove();
myList.shift().remove();
$(myList.splice(0, 1)).remove();
$(myList.splice(-1)).remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to select a specific cached item from the jQuery object, but it is little tricky to update the original cached element. I used `.not` function to filter out the removed element from the cached selector.

#### Explanation:

```
//read as numbered for better understanding
myList = myList.not( // 3. Use .not to remove the Last element from the 
                     //    cached selector
             myList.slice(-1) // 1. Select Last element using .slice(-1)
                .remove()     // 2. Remove Last element
              );
```

```js
var myList = $('.item');
console.log(myList);
myList = myList.not(myList.slice(-1).remove());
console.log(myList.css('color', 'red'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that [`$.fn.remove`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.remove) doesn't update collection elements and `length` property after it removes elements from DOM. As the result collection becomes desynchronized with actual DOM. What you can do however is to use combination of jQuery's `remove` method and native javascript `pop` or `splice`. It can be pretty concise:

```
$([].pop.call(myList)).remove();
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var myList = $('.item');

alert(myList.length);

$([].pop.call(myList)).remove()

alert(myList.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Brilliant +1, other answers are not even close.

Comment: @Vega since im a part of *"other answers"*, can you enlighten me on where I am wrong? It would help me to understand my mistake.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I am sorry, but I was not talking about being wrong. This answer was more elegant than the other answers here(including mine).

Comment: I was told about the de-syncronization, so for an example in which the DOM element is NOT removed, can I just ADD some variable to the collection (not in the actual DOM element) to retrieve it later?
 
I'm really interested in update a collection/set being run in a foreach loop, so a flagged item DOESN'T run anymore through the each().